# Typed Lambda Calculus models and denotations

Tags: reference-request, pl.programming-languages, type-theory, lambda-calculus, denotational-semantics

I'm trying to draw a general mental picture about the models and the
denotational semantics of the typed lambda calculus, in its different
variants.

I'm particularly interested in how the semantics changes according to:

1. which forms of recursion are allowed, and
2. which forms of polymorphism are allowed.

I understand that, even if one makes a precise choice about these
options, there are many possible models.  Still, I would like to pick
a few concrete examples (or even one) for each option, and draw them
in my mental picture. Of course, the simplest the better.  I feel
that, at my current stage, I do not benefit much (yet) from abstract
descriptions such as "take *any* such-and-such category" when I do not
have any idea about how to craft at least one of those.

Since the topic is quite broad, let me ask a specific question:

**What would you study next?** References are welcome.

Here's what I have seen so far:

- The STLC has a very simple set-theoretic model. Just interpret basic
  types with sets, products with cartesian products, etc. Boring but
  simple. Can be generalized to arbitrary CCCs.
- STLC + term-level recursion / fixed points. This is essentially
  PCF. We can build models using CPOs ($\omega$CPOs or DCPOs or
  ...). They are not fully abstract, but I'm not concerned with that.
  To compute fixed points, Kleene's fixed point theorem saves the day.
- PCF + type-level recursion. Here things start getting
  non-trivial. To solve type-level recursive equations, we can
  translate these to recursive domain equations, and solve them by
  lifting the Kleene $\omega$-CPO machinery at the domain level.
  Essentially, monotonic functions become functors, continuous
  functions become continuous functors, and suprema become colimits.
  Some issues arise since $\rightarrow$ is contravariant on its first
  argument, but restricting the categories at hand to
  embedding-projections pairs (which to me look like a special case of
  Galois connections) one can make everything covariant.
- Adding predicative polymorphism. By this, I mean allowing types like
  $\prod_{\tau:\sf Mono} T(\tau)$ where $\sf Mono$ is the set of monomorphic
  types, which do not contain such products. In such way, the product
  is a countable one, hence a small one, so we can take the related
  product on the CPOs for monotypes without any size issues. Shallow,
  but simple.
- Adding impredicative polymorphism, as in System F. Here
  $\prod_{\tau:*}$ ranges over all the types, including polymorphic
  ones. I'm not sure about how to proceed here. Types are still
  countable, but we can't simply relate to a polymorphic type $\tau'$
  the product of some selected CPOs as before, since such product would also involve
  the CPO of $\tau'$ itself, which we are defining.
- Adding dependent types. Ultimately I'd like to understand how a
  dependently typed semantics can be given for a language featuring
  unrestricted term-level recursion, and possibly type-level recursion
  as well. I tried to read about fibered categories, but I think I'm not yet ready to tackle those, so I'm looking for some smaller steps, first. I will try again in the future, though.

Comment: PER models seem like a natural next thing to study.

Comment: @chi, what do you count as denotational semantics?

Comment: @MartinBerger Good point. I guess I have a bias towards domain-theoretic semantics (à la Winskel's book) since I want to handle non-termination. I'm also willing to explore set-theoretical models for some terminating fragment, especially if they can be extended to cover non-termination as well. I'm not much familiar on those at the moment, though.

Comment: @chi How about logical formulae ordered by implication?

Comment: @MartinBerger You mean to interpret a lambda term as a (ordered) set of formulae? I'm trying to figure out how that would work...

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thanks. The first random paper I just browsed used a shallow approach to polymorphism: intersect all the PERs for every $\tau$ ranging over monotypes. I'll look further to find something deeper, so to encompass e.g. System F.

Comment: @chi We have a draft [here](http://users.sussex.ac.uk/~mfb21/publications/icalp06/completeness-full.pdf). It's not a very  well-developed approach currently.

Comment: For System F things are a bit more complicated. There's usually more category theory involved.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Would you recommend starting from any particular approach, even if abstract, for System F?

Comment: Maybe Paul Taylor's Appendix A of http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf, that's a classic. If you want to dive into category theory you could try the recent paper by Ghani, Nordvall and Simpson (http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-49630-5_1 or https://pure.strath.ac.uk/portal/en/publications/comprehensive-parametric-polymorphism(db9cd888-7a11-40ea-95d6-bfcfd2213d9d).html for a pdf)